Instance objects on a curve with random scales and no gaps between instances using geometry node
I instance spheres with random scales along a curve line and I use an accumulate field to remove any gaps between these spheres. What I want is to change the curve line to a Bézier Curve, so when I change the shape of the curve in edit mode, the gaps between the instances (spheres) don't change.

